# Boto3: How to list of Subnets which are not associated with any Route tables.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, boto3

How can i list Subnets which are not associated with any Route tables using boto3.?

Kindly request you to help on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Subnets will **always** have a route table attached. You **cannot** have a subnet without a route table

[Route Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html)

> Each subnet in your VPC must be associated with a route table; the
>   table controls the routing for the subnet. A subnet can only be
>   associated with one route table at a time, but you can associate
>   multiple subnets with the same route table.

Comment: This is incorrect.  A subnet can be created without a route. You can associate them later. A subnet without a route is a "blackhole".

Comment: @mootmoot A subnet is created with a default route table. In a route table, a target without a destination is called a blackhole.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. My mistake, VPC does enforce route table association.  I just delete my answer.